# Import custom css file or js file on xenforo

Tags: php, css, themes, forum, xenforo

I'm struggling through the xenforo community website with no luck and I'm really regretting xenforo doesn't provide an official development documentation.

I know you can edit the EXTRA.css entry from the admin panel, but I would like to import external files, in order to have a more efficient development workflow.

Is there a way to import a custom file on a xenforo template?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a way, still don't know if it's the best approach. So I will describe my solution here and if someone knows a better way can either comment my answer or write a new one.

- Log into the admin panel
- Go to Appereance / Style / YourActiveStyle / Templates
- open the template named "page_container_js_head" and add your file to import there

I am able now to import css and js files as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note on this, some other users place their custom links in 'ad_above_content' and works as well.

Either way, it's been confirmed that extra.css can be overwritten by values in core Xenforo as it's loaded early in the order.

Also, Xenforo will load your custom css templates alphabetically. So, the sure fire way as confirmed by theme developers is creating your own custom templates starting in 'z', such as:

If you load multiple templates, be aware of keeping them in proper order if they contain any intentional overwrites, again they will be loaded alphabetically.